# How many times is where clause evaluated in INSERT ... SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If you have a query like:

```
INSERT INTO
    insert_table
SELECT
    *
FROM
    from_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
       *
    FROM
       from_table
    WHERE
       insert_table.column = from_table.column 
);
```

Is that subquery evaluated for each row only at the initial `SELECT FROM from_table`?
My `insert_table` has a `UNIQUE` constraint that `from_table` does not, and it appears that duplicate keys exist in `from_table` and causing an error when trying to `INSERT` into `insert_table`. If the subquery would return duplicates on a particular key, they will be included in the result and attempted to be inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause is evaluated for each row in the table derived in the `from` clause.

If you need distinct keys use `distinct on`

```
insert into insert_table
select distinct on (key1, key2)  *
from from_table
where not exists (
    select
    ...
)
order by key1, key2, another_column
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: Editing my question to get clarification. The result set for the subquery is retrieved once, correct?

Answer (score 2):

The subquery **is** executed for each row. However, it's operating on a snapshot of the database, as it was at the beginning of the statement, so it won't see its own inserts.

A simpler example to illustrate this is:

```
INSERT INTO some_table SELECT * FROM some_table;
```

This will duplicate the contents of `some_table`, rather than getting stuck in an infinite loop.

This does **not** necessarily mean that the database performs the `SELECT` and `INSERT` as separate, sequential steps, but for all intents and purposes, it behaves that way; the database can "hide" these inserts, in much the same way that it "hides" uncommitted inserts by other users.

As the others have pointed out, a `SELECT DISTINCT` will fix your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are stumbling over a mix-up (additionally):

```
INSERT INTO insert_table
SELECT DISTINCT ON (unique_column) *
FROM   from_table f
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   insert_table i from_table
   WHERE  i.unique_column = f.unique_column
   )
ORDER BY unique_column, pick_first_in_case_of_dupes_column;
```

- You want to insert only rows that are not present in `insert_table`, yet.
- In addition you want to pick a single row from a set of duplicates ON `(unique_column)` in the `from_table`.

Also, for persisted statements you should add an explicit target list and a matching SELECT list, like [@Clodoaldo already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24369728/939860).